# AlpineJS – transition on page load not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm trying to fade in my element on page load with alpinejs. I thought I did everything correctly, but it's simply displaying instead of fading in. What am I doing wrong?

```
<body x-data="container">
    <main x-show="show" x-transition x-init="show = true" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen">
        test
    </main>
</body>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('container', () => ({
            show: false
        }))
    })
</script>
```

Comment: try `<body x-data="container" x-cloak>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider waiting for Alpine to finish its initialization by setting `show` to `true` within a [`$nextTick()`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick) callback.  You could also consider using [`x-cloak`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/cloak) to avoid flash of the content being shown before Alpine has initialized.

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('container', () => ({
    show: false
  }))
})
```

```css
[x-cloak] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

<body x-data="container">
  <main x-show="show" x-transition x-init="$nextTick(() => show = true)" x-cloak class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen">
    test
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems this works on Safari and Firefox, but not always on Chrome. In Chrome, If you give the x-transition.duration longer than 1000ms, it always works. Otherwise, the content sometimes just appears immediately.